# To create condition based column using Python pandas library

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to put together the following data frame in pandas.
Initially I have 3 columns.
I want to create a new column called "Status" based on condition,
**if Days_between > 7 then "New course" else "Existing Course"** for particular ID

I tried groupby with if else condition but could not put the logic correct. Any help would be appreciated.

| ID | Date | days_between | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8/21/2014 | 0 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 8/22/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 8/25/2014 | 3 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 8/26/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 8/27/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 8/28/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 8/29/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/2/2014 | 4 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/2/2014 | 0 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/3/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/4/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/5/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/8/2014 | 3 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/9/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/10/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/11/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/12/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/15/2014 | 3 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/16/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/18/2014 | 2 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/18/2014 | 0 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/19/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/22/2014 | 3 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/23/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/25/2014 | 2 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/25/2014 | 0 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/29/2014 | 4 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 9/30/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 10/1/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 10/2/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 3/9/2016 | 524 | New Course |
| 1 | 3/10/2016 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 3/11/2016 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 3/14/2016 | 3 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 3/16/2016 | 2 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 3/18/2016 | 2 | Existing Course |
| 1 | 3/21/2016 | 3 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/15/2014 | 0 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/16/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/17/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/18/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/18/2014 | 0 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/19/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/19/2014 | 0 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/24/2014 | 5 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/25/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/29/2014 | 4 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 9/30/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 10/1/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 10/2/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 10/3/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 10/6/2014 | 3 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 10/7/2014 | 1 | Existing Course |
| 2 | 10/9/2014 | 2 | Existing Course |

Comment: `df['Status'] = np.where(df['days_between'] > 7, 'New Course', 'Existing Course')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying the logic via lambda function

```
df['status'] = df['days_between'].apply(lambda x: 'New course' if x > 7 else 'Existing Course')
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different take...

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
ID  Date    days_between
1   8/21/2014   0
1   8/22/2014   8
1   8/25/2014   3
1   8/26/2014   9

'''

f = StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')

print(df)

df['Status'] = df.apply(lambda r: 'New course'
                        if r.days_between > 7 else 'Existing Course',
                        axis=1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the most efficient or canonical way to do this (I think using something akin a boolean mask would be more efficient) but this should work:

```
df['Status'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'New Course' if row['days_between'] > 7 else 'Existing Course', axis=1)
```

The lambda function is applied on a per-row basis.